# How to catch a ONE click of the button in libgdx?

Tags: button, input, libgdx

The button counts down clicks several times, but i need only one click. How can i catch only ONE click.
I was trying InputListener, EventListener, ChangeListener and ClickListener. Or is that not the problem?
Please, help me.

```
Look.addCaptureListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

                touched=true;

            }
        });

        if(!Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            OpenActions.addListener(new InputListener() {

                public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    System.out.println("X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
                    return true;
                }

                public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    System.out.println("touchup");
                }

            });
        }
```

As you see - i tried to catch only one click without the possibility to catch another one. But i failed.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Does clicking the button once cause its listener to be called several times? Or you just don't know how to stop from reacting to button presses after the first press?

Comment: Please provide some code snippets of what you're currently doing and a more precise description of what you're trying to achieve. This allows others to help since we have more information.

Comment: I still can’t tell what you’re trying to do. If you want to change a Boolean member variable when it is first clicked, add a click listener, not capture listener. You don’t need capture listeners unless you’re making advanced custom UI components. But I don’t see where you are using your touched variable after setting it. Also, you are calling your OpenActions.addListener repeatedly every frame the screen isn’t touched.

Answer (score 2):

I was added a listener to the render()(the cyclical method)... It was a mistake. I moved a listener to create(), then my problem was gone.